# Monte Carlo Integration on a unit hypercube

Tags: probability-theory, monte-carlo

Let f be a bounded borel function on the unit hypercube C=$[0,1]^d$ in $\mathbb{R}^d$.Let f be a bounded borel function defined on C.

I need to compute I=$\int_{C}f(x)dx$ by monte carlo integration as follows:Let $X_{1}$,..,$X_{n}$ be independent and uniform on C.Then $f_{n}$=$\dfrac{1}{n}\sum_{j=1}^{n} f(X_{j})$ converges almost surely to I.Let $\epsilon$>0 and find an approximate value of n such that $P(|f_{n}-I|>\epsilon)<0.05$.(We need answer in terms of some integral of f).Also can I find smallest n which works for all functions f such that $sup(|f(x)|:x\in C)\leq1$.

Comment: You know how to express (and estimate) the error in a Monte Carlo simulation?

Comment: @Calculon : No i have not studied error in a Monte Carlo Simulation. So i need procedure to proceed for the above problem.

Comment: Try Chebyshev's inequality

Comment: @BenCW: ok but i am enable to get result what they need. Will you explain in detail how to solve?

Comment: By Chebyshev, $P(|f_n - I| \ge \epsilon) \le \sigma_n^2/\epsilon^2$, where $\sigma_n^2$ is the variance of $f_n$. Thus, you need $n$ large enough that $\sigma_n^2 < 0.05\epsilon^2$. You can compute $\sigma_n^2$ and then solve for the minimal such $n$.

Comment: @BenCW:   But we need to find answer in integral of f. Can u give any hint how to solve?

Comment: The variance $\sigma_n^2$ is an integral in terms of $f$.